# div column count order top to bottom

Tags: css

When I set column-count to a div, the nested divs are ordered left to right. Is it possible to be ordered from top to bottom?

Example with column-count: 2 and items count : 5

A B
C D
E

I want :

A D
B E
C

Comment: [Do](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts) [some](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/multiple-columns/) [googling](http://davidwalsh.name/css-columns)

Comment: display some code please!

Comment: Zach, If you want post it as answer so I can accept. Ty